# Asynchronously populate Sammy.Storage cache

Tags: ajax, jquery, sammy.js

I'm having difficulty accessing `requestJSON` on a jQuery $.ajax object outside of the success callback. If I do:

```
var ajax_request = $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json'
});

console.log(ajax_request.responseJSON);

// this results in `undefined`
```

How can I access the responseJSON without adding a `.success()` callback? If I inspect `ajax_request` in Firebug, I can see the `responseJSON` property, and the data I expect, but I can't access it via:

```
ajax_request.responseJSON
```

More specifically, I'm building an SPA using Sammy and Knockout. In some routes, I need to be able to get JSON from cache, and if it doesn't exist, get the value from a service call and then set it into cache:

```
var cached_json = storage.fetch('cached_json', function() {
    // make service call
    return $.getJSON(url);
});

event_context.render('template.tpl', {'json': cached_json}).appendTo('#my-target');
```

But, of course, calling storage.fetch doesn't cause the rest of the code to pause until $.getJSON is complete. This is the part I can't quite figure out how to structure.

Comment: $.getJSON(REQUESTPARAMS)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: $.getJSON is async by default, and in some cases, I need to make a synchronous call. I'm not seeing a configuration option for .getJSON to make it synchronous...

Comment: you can not access in any way response outside without using callback function.... is there any reason not to use callback..

Comment: I added a more detailed explanation of my use case. I guess I'm having trouble restructuring my code so that the template rendering only occurs once the value is present from cache, but the call to populate the cache is async.

Comment: is not `ajax_request.responseJSON` instead `ajax_response.responseJSON`?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo on my part.

Comment: "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection." - David Wheeler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by creating a deferred object that gets or creates the value I need:

```
function get_or_create_cache(storage, key, service_endpoint) {
    return $.Deferred(function(deferred) {
        var c = storage.get(key);
        if (c === null || c === undefined) {
            $.when(jsonp_service_request(service_endpoint)).done(function(json) {
                storage.set(key, json);
                deferred.resolve(json);
            });
        }
        else {
            deferred.resolve(c);
        }
    }).promise();
}
```

In this function, `storage` refers to a Sammy.Storage instance. `jsonp_service_request` is a local function that returns a jsonp response, taking into account the `location.hostname` for local development, where I'm pointing to local.json files, or a remote environment, where I'm calling into an actual API. `jsonp_service_request` returns an `$.ajax` function.

Then in my Sammy route, I can do:

```
this.get('#/', function(event_context) {
    $.when(get_or_create_cache(storage, 'my-cache-key', 'service-endpoint'))
        .then(function(json) {
            event_context.render('my-template.template', {'value-name': json})
                .appendTo('#my-target');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here's how i would implement it

```
responseJSON = "";
$.get("myurl.php",function(jdata){
        responseJSON = jdata;
},"json");
```

i like to see the ajax method at a glace, but in your case you can do the same by

```
....
success : function(jdata){ responseJSON = jdata; }
....
```

PS: i believe that initializing the blank responseJSON is not required since any variable without var is in global scope, but it would help for clarity